# No access to my Apple developer team in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have **2** Apple accounts. One of them is a developer **paid** account. The other is a free account  added to the team of the paid developer account. When I'm logged in with the **free account** on the Apple dev website, I see the name of the **dev team** (the team that has been created by the **paid** dev account).

**My issue** is that I can't add the dev team in my Xcode project. I only have the **personal team** accessible. Then I don't have paid dev team privileges.

**How can I fix this?** Do I have to pay a developer account for both accounts? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to pay a developer account for **both accounts**. 
For example: a team of 4 developers has to buy 4 developer account for each in order to get developer privileges.